# minecraft error (java 8). (game output)

Tags: java, games, minecraft

So i have been experiencing this problem for a while and cannot figure it out on my own, so i thought it would be easier to ask other people:

I need help getting the minecraft launcher to launch MC but whenever i click on "play game" it loads, the launcher disappears then another tab pops up in the launcher called game output and then lists my username.
it says a whole bunch of other random stuff but in case it helps 
it says:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/sully22mc/.minecraft/versions/1.8.8/1.8.8-natives-57206995482525/liblwjgl64.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/sully22mc/.minecraft/versions/1.8.8/1.8.8-natives-57206995482525/liblwjgl.so: /home/sully22mc/.minecraft/versions/1.8.8/1.8.8-natives-57206995482525/liblwjgl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:96)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at ave.J(SourceFile:2539)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41)
```

Hope that helps and thanks ahead of time!

-sully

Comment: What computer do you have? That's saying it can't run a 32-bit library on ARM.

Comment: I have a CB5-311 chromebook. sorry about the wait, i have not been able to check page in a while:)

Comment: Yep, you have an ARM processor. I don't believe Minecraft can be run on ARM, not that you'd want to on that computer. If you could, the framerate would probably be around 5FPS.